# What is wrong with this dual supply op-amp cascade circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, dual-supply, cascade

At the input I have a rectangle signal, R1 and R2 are 1 kΩ and 220 kΩ on the first cascade and second cascade (amplification factor 220). At the output I have zero.

[image]

Need I something like this on the input? And why?

[image]

Comment: what specifically are you referring to in the second schematic diagram?

Comment: The last image looks like a very strange or bad way to draw supply decoupling capacitors.

Comment: Yes, decoupling capacitors would be a good idea. And yes, you do need a resistor for the input bias current of the opamp. But you don't necessarily need a signal coupling capacitor, unless the signal source has a DC bias on it you need to get rid of.

Comment: Note that the cumulated gain is ... 221^2=48841, so that "any" little "dc" offset can saturate output at high or low level ...

Comment: Let me stress Antonio's comment.  Real-world opamps have errors.  An input offset voltage error of only 100 *micro*volts will saturate the output.  What is the input signal, what is the output intended to drive, and what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

The first page of the datasheet tells you that the typical input offset voltage for this device is ±1mV. On page 14 we are told it could be as bad as ±4mV.

Even with no signal, this offset will also be subject to the combined gain of the entire system. Since the gain of the system here is \$221 \times 221 \approx 50,000\$, you can expect the output to be saturated (either high or low) before you've even applied a real signal to be amplified:

$$ 50,000 \times \pm 1mV = \pm 50V $$

Each stage has a gain of 221, meaning that in the worst case scenario of an input offset voltage of 4mV, even the first stage's output will be significantly offset:

$$ 221 \times 4mV = 0.9V $$

That offset is obviously going to be multiplied by 221 by the next stage. The easiest way to remove that DC component, and pass only AC centered about zero is by AC coupling the two stages, with C1 and R5 here:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzFoZI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Alternatively, you can achieve a similar effect with a single capacitor C1 in the second stage's feedback path to ground. This would probably work better for you, since it will remove any DC offset right up to the output:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foRXik.png)</sup>

Comment: Although the TL071 is said to have "low noise", with the circuit voltage gain as high as 48841 times, the output will probably be severely clipping noise.

Answer (score 0):

The answer - the circuit is fully worked, but the hardware was wrong because TL071 was **rotated**

[image]